# Adobe Captivate Remove "Post Results" Popup from Quiz

Tags: adobe-captivate

How to remove "Post Results" popup from the HTML 5 quiz I have made using Adobe Captive 7.?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you are still searching for the answer, but with some help and many testing, I did find a way to get rid of the popup.

The PopUp is displayed because Captivate does not know any details from the student, however it does needs these to post the results.

Captivate stores these values in the variables cpQuizInfoStudentID (for email) and cpQuizInfoStudentName (for name) and you can pass these via the URL that you use to start the course:

Instead of using the  link, you can use , this did completely remove the popup and does post the results straight after the last answer.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Post Results popup appears when "enable reporting for this project" is checked in the preferences. Please try the following:

1) From main menu, select `Quiz -> Quiz Preferences` to open the preferences dialog box

2) Select "reporting" on the left pane (just under "Quiz")

3) at the top of the dialog, uncheck "enable reporting for this project"

4) Republish your project.

Did it work? Hope so
-Patrick